# Как работает метод rfind()

Tags: python

Мне нужно найти второе вхождение буквы f. Но вместо 1 программа выводит 15. Почему?

```
s = ffffffffffffffff
f = s.rfind('f')
print(f)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

потому что

`str.find` - Возвращает наименьший индекс, по которому обнаруживается начало указанной подстроки в исходной.

`str.rfind` - Возвращает наибольший индекс, по которому обнаруживается начало указанной подстроки в исходной.

т.е. возвращается индекс от начала строки

```
s = 'ffffffffffffffff'
f = s.rfind('f')
```

соответственно ищет наибольший индекс (позицию) в которой встречается строка `f`, а это и есть `15`

т.е. данный метод НЕ СЧИТАЕТ индекс (позицию) ОТ КОНЦА строки, он СЧИТАЕТ ОТ НАЧАЛА

**P.S.**

Если же вам надо найти второе вхождение буквы `f`, то надо сделать последовательный поиск от начала

```
s = 'ffffffffffffffff'

# находим позицию первого символа 'f'
pos = s.find('f')

# находим позицию первого символа `f` после позиции первого символа
pos = s.find('f', pos + 1)

print(pos)
```

Answer (score 2):

Метод  `str.rfind()` начинает поиск с конца. Соответственно, метод возвращает первый найденный индекс начиная справа.